# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied to access selenium python through webdriver-manager

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, permissions, webdriver-manager

I recently installed webdriver-manager 2.5.2 to work with chromedriver for selenium in python. It was working fine, but now suddenly i am getting the below error-
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\mrudu\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\83.0.4103.39\win32\chromedriver.exe'

How to resolve this issue? I am new to programming so not sure how the permissions work in windows 10 and Pycharm.
Please help

Comment: I tried running PyCharm as administrator too, dint work.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i did this-
There is some process that is holding this driver. Close all Chrome drivers, and try to find all processes with name chromedriver.exe.

Solution provided by SergeyPirogov github owner for webdriver-manager